# Joomla articles by rating + rating plugin/component implementation

Tags: plugins, joomla, components, voting

I dont want to waste lots of time on creating wrong functions

**Plan:**

- It's already done, but to understand better.. I tell you :) So first thing I made: I added extra articles which are shown in main article. So it's looks like this: main article and extra nine articles in which i want to add voting.
- Eeach article(extra articles, not main article) must have rating like in youtube - like and dislike. I think of using [this script](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/07/youtube-like-rating-jquery-and-ajax.html) ( so the first question is - how to create this voting and add to these articles ? Should i create this voting plugin or component ? Or i already can add code to article view and model ? Each article will have different articles in them, based on votings and (later maybe?) on tags.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to hard code a voting script into the core Joomla content files nor should you need to create you own plugin for this. There are lots of voting plugins on JED which I think will suits you needs. You can find them here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews

One of my favourite plugins is this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews/5483

Hope this helps.